# Adding a boolean value column to a dataframe containing variable and time columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe with two columns; Variable name and the time instance in which that variable appears as follows:

```
Variable  Time
v1        t1
v2        t2
v3        t3
```

I would like to add another column with a value, this column will have a boolean value (1 or 0), 1 means the value has appeared (that instance of time) and zero outside that time instance, (t+1). Something like this:

```
Variable  Time   Value
v1        t1     1
v1        t1+1   0
v2        t2     1
v2        t2+1   0
v3        t3     1
v3        t3+1   0
```

Any ideas on how I would achieve this in python dataframe?
Cheers.

Comment: What is the data type of the `Time`  column?

Comment: @ayhan It's an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `pandas` this will do what you asked for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], 'Time': ['t1', 't2', 't3']})
df['Value'] = 1

newTime = df.Time.apply(lambda x: x + '+1')
df2 = df.copy()
df2.Time = newTime
df2.Value = 0

df = df.append(df2).sort_values('Variable').reset_index(drop=True)

df = df[['Variable', 'Time' , 'Value']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If variable column is sorted use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for mask, invert it by `~` and cast to `int` - `True`s are `1`s and `False`s are `0`s:

```
print (df)
  Variable  Time
0       v1     3
1       v1     4
2       v2     7
3       v2     8
4       v3     3
5       v3     4
6       v3     5

df['Value'] = (~df['Variable'].duplicated()).astype(int)
print (df)
  Variable  Time  Value
0       v1     3      1
1       v1     4      0
2       v2     7      1
3       v2     8      0
4       v3     3      1
5       v3     4      0
6       v3     5      0
```